# woocommerce_thankyou hook is not working after successful payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a payment gateway for woocommerce but I am facing an issue that after successful payment I am redirecting to thank you page and my order status is not updating to 'processing' or 'completed'.

I am using woocommerce_thankyou hook in my plugins main file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_epg', 'my_change_status_function', 10, 1 );

    function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment received.', 'wc-gateway-offline' ) );

    }
```

Actually in this functions before updating the status I want to send a API call to check the status of the payment and than according to the response I want to update the status of the order.

Can anybody help me in sorting this out.

Answer (score 2):

Change the hook to:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function', 20, 1 );

    function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $order_pay_method = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
        if($order_pay_method == 'epg'){
        $order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment received.', 'wc-gateway-offline' ) );
        }
    }
```

Corrected the hook.

Comment: I think woocommerce_thankyou_{$payment_method} and woocommerce_thankyou hooks are same except first one will work for specific payment method.

I tried both but none is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function', 10, 1 );

function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment received.', 'wc-gateway-offline' ) );

}
```

Comment: I think woocommerce_thankyou_{$payment_method} and woocommerce_thankyou hooks are same except first one will work for specific payment method. I tried both but none is working.

Comment: @Max have you override template file?

Comment: No, I did not override any file. Just put this code in my plugins main file.

Comment: Can you check in your woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php where it does do_action('woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id );

Put a die there and check if the execution reaches there!

Comment: Yeah I checked and unfortunately execution is not reaching to the hook because $order_id is not coming to thank you page and so if condition is  going to false. Still searching why order_id is not coming to thank you page.

Comment: After completing the payment successfully, when user is coming to thank you page, $order is showing empty here.